# I'm trying to publish an ASP.NET Core, OrchardCore WebApp to Azure from GitHub but I'm getting errors

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, orchardcore

Basically I'm trying to pblish that OrchardCore Project.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6cn4trJpFk&t=71s
It works well on local machine if I run it in visual studio.
I could even configure the CMS to suit my needs.

I could publish it to my Github.

When I try to deploy it to azure I m not successful.

I m using App service build service.

The Deployment script ends with the following lines

```
Copying file from "D:\home\.nuget\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3\2.0.2\runtimes\win-x64\native\e_sqlite3.dll" to "D:\home\site\repository\OrchardSkills.OrchardCore.OrchardCMS\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\runtimes\win-x64\native\e_sqlite3.dll".
One or more errors occurred.
Command 'starter.cmd "D:\home\site\d ...' was aborted due to no output nor 
CPU activity for 60 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.\r\nstarter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMcBC.png)

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: Which blog or official document do you use to refer to, hope to provide a web project that can be referred to, so that we can test it, and then provide a solution. There are too many projects on Github. After testing, it is no problem to publish through VS2019. But it needs to be tested again on Github.

Comment: I tried with the project under the video, and deployed successfully, even though it took  long time. Did you try follow the log? I mean increase the `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT` app setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try follow the step which works on my side:

**1. Fork the [sample project](https://github.com/OrchardSkills/OrchardSkills.OrchardCore.Disqus) to your GitHub.**
[image]

**2. Create a .net core web app on Azure portal.**

**3. Navigate to your web app -> click Deploy center -> choose GitHub.**
[image]
[image]
[image]
**4. Waiting for the deployment. (It tooks 9 minutes on my side)**
[image]
**5. Browse to the endpoint to check if it works.**
[image]